# Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

"А может все было совсем не так? "

какие знаки препинания пропущены?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

А может, все было совсем не так? -запятая после вводного слова. После А нет запятой, потому что А относится к вводному, а не ко всему предложению.Проверяем: А все было совсем не так?- смысл изменился, появился оттенок противопоставления предыдущему высказыванию.Если такой смысл Вам не нужен, запятой нет. Если нужен именно этот смысл - есть.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, возможен единственный вариант: "А может, все было совсем не так?"

Рассуждений про оттенки смыслов понять не могу, как ни стараюсь. Зачем искать чёрную кошку в тёмной комнате? Ведь её там нет.

Comment: Позвольте с Вами согласиться!

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от смысла фразы.

1) *А, может, всё было совсем не так?* - Сомнение в предыдущем высказывании

> - Почему Наполеон на Россию напал? ... Может до нефти хотел добраться.
> - **А, может, всё было совсем не так?**

2) *А может, всё было не так?* - Вопрос о возможности альтернативного развития событий.

> Значит, вы утверждаете, что гражданин N напал на вас первым... **А может, всё было совсем не так?**

3) *А может всё, было совсем не так?* - Сомнение в верной оценке всех, перечисленных выше событий.

> Но я же ей нравился? Этот взгляд на улице, задумчивый вид, неловкость, её улыбка. **А может всё, было совсем не так?** И я это просто выдумал.

4) *А может всё было, совсем не так?* - Сомнение даже в вероятности подобного события.

> - Я не сделал домашнее задание, так как меня похитили инопланетяне с Альфа-Центавры.
> - **А может всё было, СОВСЕМ не так?**